# How do I make my OpenLayer 3 map AutoPan together with my animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flask, openlayers-3

I have a Flask Application utilizing OpenLayers3 API to draw a map and animate a route. I want to be able to make the map move with my small boat if I zoom in on the boat, so that the boat never get out of view in case I am zoomed in.

I tried using some code I found [here](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/examples/animation.html) (The pan to london part):

```
// ------------------------------------------------
// Tried to use this code - Did not work
// ------------------------------------------------
/*var pan = ol.animation.pan({
  duration: 100,
  source: (map1.view.getCenter())
})
map1.beforeRender(pan);
map1.view.setCenter(currentPoint);*/
```

I have created [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m0wj9mL2/) to show off the rest of my code together with the piece above.

The marker is moving just fine, but I want the camera to pan along with the marker. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the map's view, you should call the method getView(), and to set the center, you have to pass the coordinates directly, not the geometry object.

The right approach to set the center would be:

```
map.getView().setCenter([53.44241609, 6.84913974]);
```

I also edited your [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m0wj9mL2/1/)

Comment: Thanks. This is sort of what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Zeliax please don't forget to up vote my answer if you find it right, so that everyone else can see that your problem is already solved. Thanks!